# TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable using max()

Tags: python, arrays, recursion, max, typeerror

I am trying to get the maximum between some ints using the Python max() function. However, I get this

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable.
```

This is my code:

```
def main():
    inputs =[]
    inputted = int(raw_input())
    inputs.append(inputted)
    for i in range(0,inputs[0]):
        inputted = int(raw_input())
        inputs.append(inputted)
    total = valor_max(inputs[1::], 0, len(inputs)-1)

def valor_max(array, i, j):
    if (i == j):
        return array[0]
    elif (i == (j-1)):
        return (max(array[i], array[j]))
    else:
        return  max((array[i]+min(valor_max(array, i+2, j))) , valor_max(array, i+1, j-1), array[j]+min(valor_max(array, i+1, j-1)), valor_max(array,i,j-2))

main()
```

I am getting the error in this line: `return  max((array[i]+min(valor_max(array, i+2, j))) , valor_max(array, i+1, j-1), array[j]+min(valor_max(array, i+1, j-1)), valor_max(array,i,j-2))`

Can someone explain me why cant I get my maximum that way? Thanks!

Comment: When you get an error on a large line, break the line into smaller statements, chances are you'll see your error when everything isn't nested.  Even if you don't, Python will be able to pinpoint the portion of the larger line that throws the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At some point within that line, `valor_max` is in the first case (`i == j`) and returns a single number instead of an iterable. So one of the two calls of `min` will be `min(singleNumber)` which will cause exactly the error message you see.

Instead of having your `valor_max` function return different types depending on the case, you should always try to return the same type. In your case, 
you want to return an iterable, a list or a tuple. So you should make the first case return one just like the other two cases too:

```
return (array[0], ) # this creates a tuple with a single element
```

Btw. for lines that long, it often helps to break them up into multiple statements. This not only allows you to better see what belongs to which (for example, your code has some additional parentheses around the first parameter to `max` but not to any other one), but it also allows Python to tell you exactly where the error happened instead of “somewhere in that super long line”:

```
values = (
    array[i] + min(valor_max(array, i+2, j)),
    valor_max(array, i+1, j-1),
    array[j] + min(valor_max(array, i+1, j-1)),
    valor_max(array, i, j-2)
)
return max(values)
```